# ssh: connect to host 3.140.247.171 port 22: Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, key-pair

I have a ECS cluster with some services running in them. I also have public, private keypair with me and I have a requirement to connect to the service.
Unfortunately, I couldn't connect to my service through these mentioned keypair. Can anyone  help me in how to connect to the service and eliminate the error?
Update 1: Tried to connect with Smartty with ppk file of the keys but got this error
***No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it***
I'm open to all solutions. Thanks in advance for helping me out..

Comment: EC2 or Fargate deployment of your ECS tasks?

Comment: Fargate Deployement @Mark B

Comment: Where is the SSH keypair from exactly? You can't configure ECS tasks with SSH keys. You need to enable ECS Exec in the cluster and then use that to connect. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html

Comment: My keypairs are from AWS System Manager 
I used aws ssm get parameter to extract the parameters which are my keys into ~/.ssh directory

Comment: Did you somehow configure your docker containers to pull those key files in? As far as I'm aware you cannot use SSH with ECS tasks, you have to use ECS Exec.

Comment: Yeah, I used a copy command to pull the key values into root directory